# How can I block articles referenced by article id?

Tags: articles

I have discovered that someone is systematically searching my Joomla 3.10.9 site using article id,
e.g. https://domain_name/10

This obviously only works for articles with Public access, but means that articles not yet finalised can be viewed. While a workaround may be to temporarily restrict via access type, I would prefer to restrict access so that such references forward to the home page. Articles would then only be accessible via menus or links.

I use Admin Tools but can't find any relevant firewall setting there. I've also done a Google search and found the same question but no answers.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution by changing *URL Routing* setting in *Articles > Options > Integration.*

The default is set to *Legacy*, but changing it to *Modern* triggers a 404 error if article ID is accessed directly. I have yet to fully investigate whether this change causes any problems elsewhere on the site.